# odoo/openerp server configuration option "--load"

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I wondered what exactly --load option does in odoo in server "help"
i able to find only this line which doesn't explains fully about option,

> --load=SERVER_WIDE_MODULES(Comma-separated list of server-wide modules.)

and what are server-wide modules?? and what is benefit of using this option ???

Answer (score 4):

**Server wide modules means which has loaded or installed at server wide.**

> Ex :modules like web/web_kanban

When you start odoo then first time you will open link like : http://localhost:9090/web/database/selector

It means you did not created any database but web module is loaded automatically when odoo is starting.

**You can add other module as server wise modules using following method.**

1. **Using Load**: Run your Odoo server with option

> --load=web,web_kanban,custom_server_wide_module option while running server if you do not want to specify on Odoo configuration file
>   (odoo-server.conf)

2. **Using Config File**: In configuration file (odoo-server.conf), you have to specify key for server_wide_modules as below:

> server_wide_modules = web,web_kanban,custom_server_wide_module

This may help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer and will you please explain with custom server_wide_module example... i mean in which kind of case we require to use this?

Comment: Thank you I needed to load one of my module to update the selecting page. using the config file not command options thanks